# Uninstall kodi "Unable to locate package kodi_crashlog

Tags: 14.04, package-management, kodi

I can't uninstall `kodi`:

```
sudo apt-get remove kodi*
```

This is the result.

```
E: Unable to locate package kodi_crashlog-20161211_214949.log
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'kodi_crashlog-20161211_214949.log
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'kodi_crashlog-20161211_214949.log
E: Unable to locate package kodi_crashlog-20161222_224618.log
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'kodi_crashlog-20161222_224618.log
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'kodi_crashlog-20161222_224618.log
E: Unable to locate package kodi_crashlog-20161230_193305.log
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'kodi_crashlog-20161230_193305.log
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'kodi_crashlog-20161230_193305.log
E: Unable to locate package kodi_crashlog-20170114_223009.log
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'kodi_crashlog-20170114_223009.log
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'kodi_crashlog-20170114_223009.log
```

**Ubuntu version**:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

Kodi version: `17.6 Git:20171114-a9a7a20 Media Center Kodi`

I can't understand what package is missing.

Comment: Don't worry about packages you don't have. I search with `apt-cache search ^kodi` on same Ubuntu version and don't have those neither. I'd suggest `sudo apt install -f && apt purge kodi`. This will also purge Kodi dependencies (check with `dpkg -l | grep kodi`).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are in a folder where `kodi` logfiles are stored. Your command `sudo apt-get remove kodi*` do a shell glob expansion, where `kodi*` is expanded to the logfiles in the shell before the actual `apt-get remove` command and the logfile names are passed as arguments to `apt-get remove`.

To prevent this and use the `*` in your `apt-get` command as wildcard, you have either to escape the `*` or put your arguments in quotes.

```
sudo apt-get remove kodi\*
sudo apt-get remove 'kodi*'
```

Comment: thanks for the explantion, I was thinking the '*' was for the version.